# turtlebot+hector slam possibile or not?

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to apply hector mapping on the turtlebot? Anyone did ever tried this before successfully?

Considering the poor odometry from the irobot create, I think hector slam can produce good mapping results in cluttered environment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46004/turtlebot+hector-slam-possibile-or-not?/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It won't work with the Kinect, as the FOV of the simulated laser scan is very narrow. Use with a real LIDAR is possible, however. We use it on the [hector_turtlebot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_turtlebot), which is a Turtlebot with a Hokuyo UTM-30LX mounted below the Kinect.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-10-16**:
Thanks for the reply. Are there any tutorials available for hector turtlebot?